# Outdated update information [Ubuntu][15.10]

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-15.10

I am getting an "Outdated update information" warning on the top right corner of my screen.

I try to update using the terminal and I get the warning:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is how it happened:
I tried installing a sound recorder, which was unsuccesful(or succesdul, I do not know) for reasons I do not know. Then I proceeded to uninstall a gnome sound recorder(which seemed to be the one I installed) by using

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-media
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The warning was supressed for a little while but appeared again.
Is there any easy way to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found some help as to how to fix this issue:

First off, it is not really an issue since the only thing that is off (on the surface) is the warning sign that shows up.

To remove said warning you simply access PPA (Personal Packages Archive on your computer) and remove the packages that no longer exist. This is done by following the following steps:

System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software (and unselect the packages that have the issue)

Comment: You should also do `sudo apt-get update` to see if the errors still pop up.